# Finite sum of first n integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I think I can learn something from the joke below.

I found this meme online
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i-\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}i\\
=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i+n)\\
=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-n)=-\infty$$

(I reported exactly the equation as I found it even if it is poorly written: $i$ is the sum index and not anything else).

Some comments stated that the error is in the second term of the second line, some others said the problem is in the first step.

What is wrong and, primarily, why?

Comment: The first line is an indeterminate form ($\infty - \infty$)

Comment: One cannot manipulate infinite series in the "obvious" ways unless they are known to converge. Trying to do the same manipulations of divergent series is a fallacy, for reasons precisely like this false result. Both the first the the third equalities suffer from this error.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, the following equation is *invalid*: $$\sum_{1}^{n}i=\sum_{1}^{\infty}i-\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}i.$$

Comment: The sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i$ **does not exist.** You cannot do algebra with it.

Comment: So (as expected) essentially everything is invalid, great! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the facts that are mentioned in the comments under the question:

The sum $\sum_{1}^{\infty}i$ is divergent.

The sum $\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}i$ is divergent.

The difference of two divergent sums is meaningless. Specifically,
you cannot say that
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}i - \sum_{n+1}^{\infty}i$$
is equal to anything, let alone say it is equal to $\sum_{1}^{n}i$.
So the joke is that the very first equation is already nonsense.